# I want to use single quotation inner text of div element.It gives error how can I solve this issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I load div's inner html automatically with names of city. It loads fine but there is one problem. If a city name contains **single quotation** or if it is contains **(** or **)** it gives error again. Because these are special chars for javascript. How can I solve this issue?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
div.innerHTML = "this city\'s name";
```

And it will end up being:
this city's name

For reference: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp

Comment: What do you mean? I didn't downvote.

Answer (score 0):

You mean

```
 document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "'(helo)(or)He";
```

It works fine.

Comment: I use this format  $("#Header").html(sCaption ); **scaption contains special chars**